# AS3 > Starting class on certain frame? TypeError :Error #1006

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to create a simple memory game  i have 3 frames Intro ,Main Game , End however every time i click the "start button" to jump to frame 2 i keep getting this error;

```
TypeError: Error #1006: Play_AnimalCardGame is not a function.
    at AnimalCardGame/frame2()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at AnimalCardGame/startGame()
```

My .AS

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;


    public class Play_AnimalCardGame extends MovieClip
    {
        private static const boardWidth:uint =4;
        private static const boardHeight:uint =3;
        private static const cardVSpace:Number=100;
        private static const cardHSpace:Number=15;
        private static const offSetX:Number=115;
        private static const offSetY:Number=155;






        public function Play_AnimalCardGame ():void
        {





            var cardDeck:Array = new Array();
            for ( var i:uint=0;i<boardWidth*boardHeight/2;i++){
                cardDeck.push(i);
                cardDeck.push(i);
            }

            for(var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth ; x++){
                for(var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight;y++){
                    var aCard:Card = new Card();
                    aCard.stop();
                    aCard.x = x*offSetX+cardVSpace;
                    aCard.y = y*offSetY+cardHSpace;
                    var randomCard:uint = Math.floor(Math.random()*cardDeck.length);
                    aCard.cardface= cardDeck[randomCard];
                    cardDeck.splice(randomCard,1);
                    aCard.gotoAndStop(1);
                    aCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickCard);
                    addChild(aCard);
                    cardLeft++;

                }

                }



        }
        private var firstPick:Card;
        private var secondPick:Card;
        private var cardLeft;
        private static const pointHit:int =100;
        private static const pointMiss:int = -5;
        private var startscore =0;
        var startTime:uint;
            var time:uint;

        public function clickCard(event:MouseEvent){



                    var pickedCard:Card = (event.currentTarget as Card);

                    if(firstPick == null){
                        firstPick =pickedCard;
                        firstPick.gotoAndStop(pickedCard.cardface+2);
                    }
                    else if (firstPick ==pickedCard){
                        firstPick.gotoAndStop(1);
                        firstPick=null;
                    }
                    else if (secondPick ==null){
                        secondPick= pickedCard;
                        secondPick.gotoAndStop(pickedCard.cardface+2);

                        if (firstPick.cardface == secondPick.cardface){
                            startscore +=pointHit;
                            cardLeft-=2;
                            removeChild(firstPick);
                            removeChild(secondPick);

                            txtscore.text= String(startscore);
                            firstPick = null;
                            secondPick=null;
                        }
                        else{
                            firstPick.gotoAndStop(1);
                            secondPick.gotoAndStop(1);

                            startscore +=pointMiss;
                            txtscore.text= String(startscore);

                            secondPick=null;
                            firstPick = pickedCard;
                            firstPick.gotoAndStop(pickedCard.cardface+2);
                        }

                    }
                    if(cardLeft==0){
                            gotoAndStop("gameover");
                    }
                }
    public function showTimer(event:Event)
        {

            startTime = getTimer();
            time=0;

            time = getTimer()- startTime;
            txtTime.text = clockTime(time);
        }

    public function clockTime(ms:int){
        var seconds:int = Math.floor(ms/1000);
        var minutes:int = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        seconds -=minutes *60;

        var timeString:String = minutes+":"+String(seconds+100).substr(1,2);
        return timeString;
    }


}
```

From what i can there are no problems but then again in still only learning

Comment: What is your code on frame2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've defined the class name as

```
Play_AnimalCardGame
```

but then you define the constructor as

```
AnimalCardGame
```

Start by setting the constructor name to the same as the class name

Comment: @juggles Im still getting the Same error even after the change :/

Comment: What's the code on your start button and what are you calling on frame 2?  Technically, Play_AnimalCardGame is not a function.  It is an object. An object can contain functions that can be called, but you can't call Play_AnimalCardGame();